# Why is $\textbf{J}$ called angular momentum?(Quantum)

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

Why is $\textbf{J}$ called angular momentum operator? Can anyone explain why the expectation value of J is angular momentum?

Here is how $\textbf{J}$ is defined: The rotation operator
$$
U(\alpha)=\exp(-i {\bf \alpha} \cdot \mathbf{J})
$$
Rotates the system around the direction of $\alpha$, through an angle $|\alpha |$.

Sorry that this is not quite research level, but I cannot find some intuitive explanation about this elsewhere.

Comment: This question might be more suitable at https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: this is explained, for example, here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_operator_(quantum_mechanics)

Comment: @GHfromMO This question is put on hold at PhysicsSE

Comment: Personally, I don't understand your questions. Your first sentence refers to an operator $\mathbf{J}$, but this symbol is left undefined. Second, it is not clear what you mean by expectation value of an operator. Third, you talk about J and $J$, but you do not explain its connection to $\mathbf{J}$. Finally, your display does not define $\mathbf{J}$: it defines $U(\alpha)$ in terms of (the undefined) $\mathbf{J}$.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/382765/2451 and https://hsm.stackexchange.com/q/6993/1945

Comment: isn't the answer just that $\mathbf{J}=\mathbf{r}\times\mathbf{p}$, with $\mathbf{r}$ the position operator and $\mathbf{p}=-i\nabla$ the momentum operator? If this is not the answer you want, you will need to be more precise in stating what is your question.